# Powermock private Singleton Constructor with Mockito argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, powermock

I have a singleton class with a private constructor. That private constructor takes in an object of some other class. I need to call a public method from that singleton class in order to test that method. I am unable to do so.

This is what I did:

Create a mock of object that needs to be passed to the singleton class's private constructor in the test class:

```
@Mock
private SomeClass someObject;
```

Then I try to mock the private constructor of the singleton class SomeSingletonClass:

```
   SomeSingletonClass mockSingleton = PowerMock.createMock(SomeSingletonClass);
    PowerMock.expectNew(SomeSingletonClass).andReturn(mockSingleton);
```

This is when the `SomeSingletonClass` constructor didnt have an argument. But I need to pass it mocked `someObject` of `SomeClass`. How do I do that?

After that problem gets solved, how do I call the following public non-static method of `SomeSingletonClass`:

```
public XYZClass someMethod(int 1, String 2){

//some logic

return (Object of XYZClass)
}
```

I am completely new to all of this so any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

**EDIT**

If I try to call `someMethod` from the `mockSingleton` object like:

`mocksingleton.someMethod`

then I get java.lang.NoClassDefFound error.